# How to INSERT INTO [second temp table] FROM [stored procedure returning two tables]

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have an existing stored procedure that essentially returns two tables, the first table being just one integer in an unnamed column, and the second table has rows of named columns.

I need to build a new stored procedure that executes the existing stored procedure and uses the data from the second table returned by the existing stored procedure, and ignores the first table/integer.

The following is my attempt at it, but it returns the error, "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition" because of that first table/integer.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[New_StoredProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
CREATE TABLE #temptable(X VARCHAR(20), Y INT, Z VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #temptable(X, Y, Z)
EXEC [Existing_StoredProcedure]
    @a = '1',
    @b = '2',
    @c = '3'

SELECT * FROM #temptable
DROP TABLE #temptable
END
```

Is there a way for to write this that ignores the first table/integer?

Comment: No, there's no workaround for it. See [`INSERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335.aspx): "If *execute_statement* is used with INSERT, each result set must be compatible with the columns in the table or in column_list." There's no ifs, buts or excepts, just that statement.

Comment: There is no T-SQL way to read the second or further result set.  However it is possible using a [SQLCLR extended procedure](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/da5328a7-5dab-44b3-b2b1-4a8d6d7798b2/insert-into-table-one-or-multiple-result-sets-from-stored-procedure?forum=transactsql).

Comment: Is the output from `[Existing_StoredProcedure]` stored in temp, global temp, or perm tables?

Comment: Or you can add an addtional parameter to your stored procedure to control which result set is returned, and than at run time you decide what result set to return by passing values to that parameter.

Comment: It looks like the least invasive way of doing this would be to just call the existing stored procedure from my .NET source code and get the second table that comes back, then get the result from my new stored procedure, and then do my data manipulations and merging in the code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way you can control the returned result set will be adding an additional parameter which will decied how many and which result sets are returned when a stored procedure is called.

For example in your `[Existing_StoredProcedure]` you can do something like .....

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Existing_StoredProcedure]
@a    VARCHAR(10),
@b    VARCHAR(10),
@c    VARCHAR(10),
@ResultSet INT = NULL    --<-- Indicator Param
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  -- Common code that executes regardless of what result set is required


  -- Now return the result set based on value passed to @ResultSet       
  IF (@ResultSet = 1 OR @ResultSet IS NULL)
    BEGIN
       -- Code for 1st result set  
    END

  IF (@ResultSet = 2 OR @ResultSet IS NULL)
    BEGIN
       -- Code for 2nd result set  
    END

END
```

Now if you dont pass any value to `@ResultSet` param both result sets will be returned but if you pass 1 or 2 , only relative result set will be returned.